# Why isn't this working? I'm having trouble figuring it out

Tags: c++

```
    //I don't understand why this isn't working
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    main ()
    {
     double pizzaDiameter;
     int numSlices;
     double area;

     cout << "Pizza diameter: "    ;
     cin >> pizzaDiameter;

    area = (pizzaDiameter/2.0) * (pizzaDiameter/2.0) * 3.14159;

    numSlices = area/14.125;

    cout << numSlices << " slices ";
    }
```

When I worked on this program in myprogramminglab.com it said that it was correct.  However, when I run it in visual studio it says there is an error.  I just don't get it.

Comment: You should at least tell us what the error is. I notice `main` has no return type, which isn't legal C++ at all (think C).

Answer (score 2):

`main` should have a return type of `int`:

```
int main()                                                                     /*
^^^                                                                            */
{ ... }
```

As for everything else, it looks fine. [Here is a working demo.](http://ideone.com/LFRXZg#view_edit_box)